# Wildfly 8 to 9: Datasources can´t get migrated

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc, wildfly

i´m trying to use the new wildfly 9.0.1 final. Before, i used wildfly 8.2.
I´ve copied the standalone/config folder from 8.2 to the new wildfly 9- but getting a lot of errors- it looks like he can´t add the datasources...But allready deployed the mssql driver to new wildfly:

17:09:48,419 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "WebEventLogs")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.data-source.java:/jdbc/WebEventLogs is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mssql]",
    "jboss.driver-demander.java:/jdbc/WebEventLogs is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mssql]",
    "jboss.data-source.java:/jdbc/WebEventLogs is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mssql]"
]}

17:09:48,434 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "ShoppingPortletLocal")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.driver-demander.java:/shoppingPortletPU is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mssql]",
    "jboss.data-source.java:/shoppingPortletPU is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mssql]",
    "jboss.data-source.java:/shoppingPortletPU is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mssql]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you haven't deployed the JDBC driver module:

```
 "jboss.data-source.java:/shoppingPortletPU is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mssql]"
```

Make sure you have your MS SQL JDBC Driver deployed. It's usually deployed as a module, on `$WILDFLY_HOME/modules`.

Comment: Thank you!
I´ve now copied the following folder with the mssql driver jar from "wildfly-8.2.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\com\microsoft\sqlserver\jdbc\main" to the same folder in wildfly 9- now it works :)

But thats strange, that wildfly 9 didnt created the folder with the driver- cause i also deployed it on em...